# Why do we have only one migration destination?

Tags: discussion, migration

The only migration destination I found is UL meta (here). I say this because I saw that SO has five. Destinations I can think for are SO, SU, AU.

Comment: I think SF too, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is people here don't vote to close. Most posts are closed by a mod and nobody else; in the last 4 months the only votes to close besides mods are [Shawn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2180/shawn-j-goff) once, [Stefan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4/stefan-lasiewski) twice, and [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) a handful of times. Either that means few posts need to be closed on UL, or it means posts only get closed if a mod notices them. If it's the former than that's good, but we're unlikely to warrant migration paths; if it's the latter than we don't know where we need to migrate to, because we can't check the closed posts to find out.

Mods can migrate now, but it doesn't happen as much as you might think. So far this year:

#### Migrations to us from X

- SO - 38
- SU - 3
- AU - 3

#### Migrations from us to X

- SO - 3
- SU - 4
- AU - 4

---

The only one that would really be useful is a target to us from SO, but they don't have room on their close dialog (the max is 5). I looked into replacing [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), since I figured they have the lowest migration volume from SO, but SO pushes around 30 questions to webmasters every **week**, so having pushed 40 to us in two months is probably not enough to warrant replacing them

Comment: I don't think the problem is "people here" failing to do something, so much as that there's only a handful of people with enough reputation points to do it. That's a situation which will get better.

Comment: @mattdm Well, in theory we stayed in beta long enough to get people up to 3k (see the bold text in [this post](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263/beta-progress-importance-of-reputation-and-voting/264#264)). In practice, it looks like having exactly five closers isn't enough, especially when two of them are mods. We're up to 12 total now, but it's still not enough. I think the real cause is the second part of my sentence though -- we just don't have that many posts to close. We don't have migration paths because we legitimately don't need them

Comment: It's true, I haven't really seen a lot of questions that are misplaced (and I flag 'em when I do.)

Comment: @mattdm and an unfortunate thing about being a mod, we can't vote to close... to see if others agree... our votes are final.

Answer (score 2):

You can have other migration destinations, but they must be based on data.

Take a look at your closed off-topic questions and see if there is a pattern of where those questions would belong elsewhere in the network.

If there is strong evidence that a lot of closed off-topic questions belong on a particular site we will unlock that migration route.